# Ratios for Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that looks like this:

```
           Band A      Band B      Band C
Dep 1      12          300         17
Dep 2      92          450         23
Dep 3      7           989         121
```

I need to be able to show the ratio of each Dep and Band vs. each other Dep and Band. E.g.

```
Dep1 BandA vs. Dep2 BandA = 0.13 : 1
Dep1 BandA vs. Dep2 BandB = 0.026 : 1 etc...
```

Is there an easy + automated way to calculate and show these instead of having to do it manually?

Comment: you can pivot the pivot

Comment: I'm not sure how that would do what I need it to do